# Constraint check condition adding current date

Tags: sql-server

I have tried the following code

```
CONSTRAINT employees_hire_date_ck CHECK (WHERE hire_date=NULL THEN curr_date ELSE hire_date END)
```

i need to assign current date if  my column `hire_date` is null using constraint check condition in sql server

Answer (score 0):

Try 
CASE WHEN hire_date IS NULL THEN GETDATE()

ELSE 
hire_date

END AS hire_date

Comment: Thanks for your answer.CONSTRAINT employees_hire_date_ck CHECK (case when hire_date is null then getdate() else hire_date end as hire_date);;I am getting syntax error as an expression of non boolean type is specified in a context where condition expected

Comment: Please attach your exact query

Comment: Here is my query       create table em
(emp_id numeric(5,0),
hire_date date,
CONSTRAINT em_hire_date_ck CHECK(case when hire_date is null then getdate() else hire_date end=hire_date)); When I execute i am still getting null values in hire_date column

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use a calculated column or a trigger for this purpose.

```
,employees_hire_date as case when [hire_date] is null 
                             then curr_date 
                             else hire_date end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.CONSTRAINT employees_hire_date_ck
CHECK (case when [hire_date] is null then curr_date else hire_date end);I am getting syntax error as an expression of non boolean type is specified in a context where condition expected